# Weblogic Server: Copy files to shared location within network using Java

Tags: java, weblogic12c

Our application is deployed on weblogic server 12c. This application needs to copy files from server to some folder on the network location. 
How can this be achieved in Java?

Application code is like

```
        String source = 
        "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains 
        \base_domain\pdf_files\ABC.pdf";//Location on server
        String destination = "\\machineA\SharedFolder";//shared folder in some machine on same network

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);            
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Getting a error message 
       java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\machineA\SharedFolder\ABC.pdf (Access is denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

machineA(server) can be added in the shared folder's Sharing options as machineA$.
Then this code which is running from application server will be able to access the location.

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account